# Send binary data from nodejs (request) to java (ZipInputStream)

Tags: java, node.js, upload, binary

For some reason zip files produced on nodeJS gets rejected on a Java server where you can only use "binary" data upload.

If I post the file with Postman using binary it works fine, but when sending through nodeJS (request/request-promise/http ...etc) it does not work.

It gives:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:310)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:122)
        at com.ws...
```

The files are valid (it accepts via postman!)

Answer (score 0):

Spent nearly two days on this issue. Read through tons on stack overflow post (most of them did not have proper answer in this specific topic) and googled around, but all the efforts in vain.

I kept experimenting and the only solution which seemed to work just fine is using child process and curl...

In case someone else falls into this really annoying problem:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var args = "-X POST \
  https://mywebsite.com/zip-upload \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer gFChWxzeCIZVLM2q...WlvDB6zq2uOHfUcdX' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/zip' \
  --data-binary @./data.zip";

exec('curl ' + args, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, **child_process** is the last choice. If you have tried *request* or *request-promise* and failed, how about trying **[htp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htp)**:

```
const htp = require('htp');
htp.post(
    "https://mywebsite.com/zip-upload", 
    { "Authorization" : "earer gFChWxzeCIZVLM2q...WlvDB6zq2uOHfUcdX"
    , "Cache-Control" : "no-cache"
    , "Content-Type"  : "application/zip"
    },
    fs.createReadStream("./data.zip")
)
.then(function(response) { /* ... */ })
.catch(function(error) { /* ... */ })
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this can not send data as binary. (see title & curl flags)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. In my case, I was using custom value for `Content-Type` (e.g. - "application/abc+json") to upload a zip file via `POST` request in `fetch()`. It was working in Postman, but not in nodejs server.

**I was able to get it working by adding `Content-Length` as header before making request via `fetch()`**.

Request headers I used - `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, `Authorization`, and bunch of other API specific headers.

Hopefully this helps anyone facing issue.